# Can the network admin access folder structure of my personal laptop over VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, forticlient

I need to connect my office PC ( desktop ) from home, the office PC runs 24/7. I was given a **forclient** enterprise VPN app by our network admin.
He told me to install **Forticlient** on my personal laptop then connect VPN then via RDC, connect to office desktop. This connection process i understand.
But i have some doubts regards to my network admin. When i use their VPN and connect to to their VPN network and RDC to office desktop, can the network admin of my
office, access my home personal laptop's folders without me knowing about it?

My understanding of network is that the network admin in my office can access my home personal laptop's folders, only if i give him the user & password ( Admin or Non-Admin Password ) of the laptop? am i correct....cus if some one tries to connect to my personal laptop, first he would need to enter my windows login user & password to access the folders in it right?

Comment: VPN tunnels are between a client & server and a server cannot initiate communication with a client, nor should a client by default be able to access another client on the VPN without manual configuration _(what you're concerned about and is a recommended question you may want to ask)_. You could firewall inbound VPN subnet traffic, however the configuration to do so will vary with the environment and type of VPN [IPSec, SSL, or Wiregaurd] to ensure inbound requests initiated by your client are allowed through, but not new requests from the VPN server beyond DHCP and possibly DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, the VPN tunnel itself doesn't allow access to your host.
However, theres another issue to consider:

> He told me to install Forticlient on my personal laptop

Although the tunnel created by that app may not expose a security hole for your personal laptop, installing software you received from someone definitely does.
That software may very well be a VPN client, however it may also do a number of other things, from installing a keylogger to opening another backdoor.
Unless you have some way of verifying the software (and I'm assuming you don't) you can't rule it out.